# Google Calendar: Cross-user overlapping allowed and disallowed events

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone.

I would like to know how the Android Calendar app manages the following use cases:

- you and another user registered with the Google Calendar app on your phone have events that overlap in time (perhaps these are work events and you and your partner both have some events at work on the same day but work in different places)
- you want to schedule an event at a time your partner has already an event, but, in those hours, you must be together, so, you cannot schedule distinct overlapping events as you must schedule a single activity in which you must both take part at the same time

How does Google Calendar manage these two so different scenarios?

Is there any third parties calendar apps that integrate with Google Calendar that cater to this difference in some way, taking care of displaying thighs properly and warning you of overlaps?

Screenshots welcome.

Thank you for your answers.

Please migrate my post to the user experience (UX) stack exchange if more appropriate there.

Thanks.